# item:saving event is triggered for Schedule Task items on CMS refresh

Tags: events

I'm working on logging item events using custom handlers. I observe that whenever the CMS page is refreshed or an item is created, the `item:saving` and `item:saved` events are being triggered and those items are of the template - `/sitecore/templates/System/Tasks/Schedule`

Examples:
`/sitecore/system/Settings/Email/Instance Tasks/Content Management Primary/Message Statistics/Today`

Is that expected and is there a way to disable auto saving of such items.

**Patch.config:**

```
<events>
   <event name="item:created">
      <handler type="Basiscore.CmsAudit.Handlers.ItemEventHandler, Basiscore.CmsAudit" method="OnItemCreated"/>
   </event>      
   <event name="item:saving">
      <handler type="Basiscore.CmsAudit.Handlers.ItemEventHandler, Basiscore.CmsAudit" method="OnItemSaving"/>
   </event>
   <event name="item:saved">
      <handler type="Basiscore.CmsAudit.Handlers.ItemEventHandler, Basiscore.CmsAudit" method="OnItemSaved"/>
   </event>      
</events>
```

**ItemEventHandler.cs**

```
public class ItemEventHandler
{
  public void OnItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
     ...
  }
  
  public void OnItemSaving(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
     ...
  }

  public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item:saving` and `item:saved` events are not triggered on refresh of the page in CMS. There is no functionality like that in Sitecore, unless your project has a really really strange custom code.

Yes, `item:saving` and `item:saved` are triggered when an item is created - that's how Sitecore works and there is no way of disabling that. Plenty of Sitecore functionality depends on that and you don't want to break it.

If you don't want to execute your code on `item:saving` or `item:saved` for items of a given template, you can add a condition that will return before executing your audit functionality if item is of a certain template.

The item you mention in your question

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Email/Instance Tasks/Content Management Primary/Message Statistics/Today`

is a built-in scheduled task responsible for updating statistics of EXM messages. It's configured to be executed every 1 hour by default (in Sitecore 10).

You can easily disable it by changing `Schedule` field of that item from value like

```
20090326T112200|20990426T112200|127|00:01:00
```

to

```
20090326T112200|20090426T112200|127|00:01:00
```

That means the schedule won't be executed after 26th of April 2009 anymore.

Remember that if you use EXM, statistics will NOT be populated anymore.

Comment: I can confirm that there is no such strange custom code. Because this is my local instance and I have never worked on those "Task Schedule" items. But when I refresh the CMS, the `Today` item is updated each time and I can see its date field being updated.

Comment: That's a scheduled task item - apparently there is a scheduled task which is executed quite frequently in your system and which updated that particular item. Read more about scheduled tasks in Sitecore here: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2017/08/18/sitecore-scheduled-task-schedule-time-format-and-other-quirks/

Comment: I have handled it buy adding a condition to exclude items from certain templates, but this behaviour seems odd. I do not need Sitecore to keep updating Scheduled task items when I'm not using them...right. So, is there any config setting to disable them.

Comment: See updated answer